# UISegmented control being reloaded on UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a dynamic UITableView. On the first row of the first section I have a segmentedControll (everything with prototype cells, subclassing and delegating to the UITableViewController). With this segmented control I want an additional row to appear on the very same section. What I do is to have a conditional on the `numberOfRowsInSection` and then when the SegmentedControl is tapped it triggers the following:

```
  if (cellPath.section==0 && cellPath.row==1) {

        if (segmentedCell.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {

            reverse=NO;

           [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        }else if (segmentedCell.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1){

            reverse=YES;

            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

 }

}
```

it somehow works, but the problem is that the SegmentedControl also gets reloaded at its initial state and you can inmagine the rest.

Any idea on how to workaround this? I've also tried reloadRowsAtIndex..., but doesn't work (I did put the begin/end ).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload a table the cell are "reused".  So each cell will not store state but relies on another class (delegate) to hold the state.  So if you wish to maintain the state on your segmented control, then store its value in the delegate for your table view and then ensure you set that value to your segmented control in you cellForRowAtIndexPath each time for its index path.